# MVC3 Remote Attribute - validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class Admin:

```
    public class Admin
    {
        public virtual int AdminId { get; set; }

        [Remote("UsernameAvailable", "Admins")]
        [Display(Name = "lblUsername", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Admin.Controllers.Admins))]
        public virtual string Username { get; set; }
...
```

then i have a viewmodel class that's used for a view:

```
   public class AdminsEditViewModel 
    {

        public Admin Admin { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectAdminsInGroup { get; set; }
...
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult UsernameAvailable(string Username)
{
    return Json(this.AdminRepository.GetLoginByUsername(Username), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

However string Username is always null because what is sent to Action is this:

```
http://localhost/admin/admins/usernameavailable?Admin.Username=ferwf
```

The problem is that UsernameAvailable sends Admin.Username value and NOT Username value in the http query. how would I do it using a view model?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could specify a prefix to the default model binder:

```
public ActionResult UsernameAvailable([Bind(Prefix = "Admin")]string username)
{
    return Json(
        this.AdminRepository.GetLoginByUsername(username), 
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    );
}
```

or use your `Admin` model:

```
public ActionResult UsernameAvailable(Admin admin)
{
    return Json(
        this.AdminRepository.GetLoginByUsername(admin.Username), 
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    );
}
```

Now `username` parameter will be correctly bound assuming the following request:

```
http://localhost/admin/admins/usernameavailable?Admin.Username=ferwf
```

Comment: I would recommend the second approach, basically think of it like just another action method, in that case the default model binder would bind Admin, not the username string.

Comment: that worked. however I had to bind to "AdminViewModel" and not "Admin" like so: public ActionResult UsernameAvailable(AdminsEditViewModel row)