# How do you execute an asp.net mvc route given its name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Given a routename, I know I can get the route by querying the RouteTable but how do I go about actually executing the controller action that the route points to and obtaining the result?

To avoid confusion, I should point out that I want to execute the controller action and examine the result, not render it, redirect to it or link to it. I am doing this is in a subclass of ValidationAttribute, but this should not matter. The important thing is that it is in server-side code and not in the view. In addition, the controller action is not returning a view or partialview, but other kinds of result including JsonResult. I can hard code the controller and action using:

```
var controller = (DefaultController)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(DefaultController));

var result = controller.ValidateUsername(username) as JsonResult;
```

but I need to be able to do it using just a routeName string.

I hope this is less vague.

More info:

I am just trying to do something similar to the built-in remoteattribute validator that works on the client and server. For the client, it outputs html-5 data attributes that hook in to a jquery function that uses ajax to call back to the controller action and returns the result as json. The js then examines the result and renders an error message if incorrect. For the server-side validation, you typically override the IsValid method of ValidationAttribute and put in your validation logic. In my case, this involves executing the controller action specified (ie the same action that is called by the js) and parsing the result. Therefore, given a routename (or a controllername and actionname if easier), I want to execute the action, and parse the result which in this case is a JsonResult.

Comment: Would this be from within an action? Could you provide an example situation.

Comment: In a custom validator. It is similar to the built-in RemoteAttribute in MVC 3 that takes in a routeName or controller and action name.

Comment: what is the ASP.NET MVC version? 1, 2, 3? always add this as a tag

Comment: @The Flower Guy If you're going to edit your question, at least include the code and the fact that you're using a custom validator, none of which is in your original question (yet you've made two comments on answers that it is.)

Comment: @The Flower Guy It is also helpful if you tell us why you're doing it this way, instead of the standard way. That way we'd be able to understand what constraints you're operating under.

Answer (score 2):

It appears there's a [Stack Overflow answer to your question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833725/mvc3-remote-attribute-validation).  As far as using the RouteName -- you can't. In fact, you have to [institute a hack just to get access to the RouteName](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/11/28/getting-the-route-name-for-a-route.aspx).

If you're willing to go poking through the [ASP.NET MVC source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets), you could create a way yourself, but there's no built in way.

Answer (score 1):

There are several **Redirects** methods at your disposal, for your particularly question use in your `Action`:

```
return RedirectToRoute("RouteName");
```

---

> Next time write the proper question, and don't be rule down voting something that you never asked !

---

Without any more explanation it's hard to know what are you doing!

Comment: I want the result of the action, not a redirect. Additionally, I have specified that it is being called from a custom validator, not an action.

Comment: @The Flower Guy no where in your original question did you say it was being called from a custom validator.